Calculate polygons angles to horizon using FME
I have a lot of polygons that represent buildings and I want to rasterise them but before I do I need all the polygons to be parallel to the horizon. I need to create a FME tool that calculates the polygon angles and then use these angles to rotate the buildings accordingly.
Done.


I have tried to use HorizontalAngleCalculator but the results were not good.

I have managed to complete the FME script to calculate the Angle of the polygons and use these Angle to rotate them.
